# How to run transaction on every document in collection in Firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update the documents in collection. But I would like to run transaction for every document:

```py
async def example():
    @google.cloud.firestore.async_transactional
    async def update_in_transaction(transaction: AsyncTransaction, city_ref, data):
        transaction.get(city_ref)
        transaction.update(city_ref, data)

    db: google.cloud.firestore.AsyncClient = AsyncClient()
    await db.collection("1").document("1").set({"a": 1})
    await db.collection("1").document("2").set({"a": 2})

    docs = db.collection("1").stream()
    async for doc in docs:
        transaction = db.transaction()
        await update_in_transaction(transaction, doc, {"a": 3})

asyncio.run(example())
```

But I think that I read twice under this approach : first time on `async for` and the second - on `get()`.

Is there any way to avoid excessive read in my case?

Comment: Have you checked this documentation on [transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)?

Comment: @RobertG yes i did